# Why useTranslation show the key not the value

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-i18next

[image][image][image][image]
I'm Using next-i18next Why it always show the key ? no matter what locales I set for default or the key is in common file or not it always give me the key not the value is there a provider what I should wrap my layout in it

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not an image.

Comment: I dont have any error its just not working